# Desabilitar button enquanto a requisição é realizada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo uma tela de adicionar membros e quando o membro é adicionado o usuário já visualiza em uma tabela abaixo (AJAX).

Quando os usuários estão clicando no botão adicionar a requisição pode demorar, dependendo de "N" fatores, e quando demora, os usuários continuam clicando no botão de adicionar, o que acarreta em várias inserções e vários registros "idênticos" na tabela.

Eu quero simplesmente dar um disable no botão enquanto a requisição é finalizada e a tabela atualizada, porém não manjo muito de JS.

Meu código:

```
$('form#{$model->formname()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e)
{

    var \$form = $(this);

    $.post(
        \$form.attr("action"),
        \$form.serialize(),
    ).done(function(result){  
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#membros'});
        $(\$form).trigger("reset");
    }).fail(function(){
        $(\$form).trigger("reset");
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#membros'});
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$('form#{$model->formname()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e)
{

    var \$form = $(this);
    var botao = $('#id_do_seu_botao');

    botao.prop('disabled', true);

    $.post(
        \$form.attr("action"),
        \$form.serialize(),
    ).done(function(result){  
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#membros'});
        $(\$form).trigger("reset");
        botao.prop('disabled', false);
    }).fail(function(){
        $(\$form).trigger("reset");
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#membros'});
        botao.prop('disabled', false);
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

Assim antes da requisição ele desabilita o botão, e no termino da requisição ele o habilita.

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Vlw mesmo :)

Answer (score -1):

Substitua sua requisição para `$.ajax`. Nela temos as funções:

`beforeSend`: essa função é executada antes de ser realizada a requisição *AJAX*, no seu caso, aqui devemos desabilitar o botão.

`success`: essa função é executada caso a requisição *AJAX* tenha sido executada pelo back-end com sucesso.

`error`: essa função é executada caso ocorra alguma falha na requisição do back-end.

`complete`: essa função é executada depois do `success` ou do `error` (depende se sua requisição foi realizada com sucesso para chamar uma das duas). No seu caso, iremos usar essa função para habilitar o botão novamente.

```
var \$form = $(this);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: \$form.attr("action"),
    data: \$form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        // Aqui desativamos seu botão, troque para o id correto
        $('#id-botao').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#membros'});
        $(\$form).trigger("reset");
    },
    error: function(xhr) { 
        $(\$form).trigger("reset");
        $.pjax.reload({container:'#membros'});
    },
    complete: function() {
        // Aqui habilitamos seu botão, troque para o id correto
        $('#id-botao').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Vale lembrar-te que o perguntante utiliza uma versão mais recente da biblioteca do jQuery. Seu exemplo não compete com a pergunta. A teoria sim poderia ser considerada, mas o código não. Propriamente dito, seu código forçaria o perguntante a "atrasar" a versão da biblioteca dele. Veja mais em [jQuery - ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): *Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead*.